# Python Inheritance: Importing from another python file

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm having trouble linking these two python files (through the concept of Inheritance). Below is what my code looks like so far (linked). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

question.py file (https://pastecode.xyz/view/362833be)
questiondemo1.py file (https://pastecode.xyz/view/cb9c13a8)

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in the question, not behind a link that might go dead at any point.

Comment: *What* trouble do you have? Do you get an error? Are you unsure how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your file questiondemo1.py first line is :

```
from question import Question
```

However, the name of first file is "questions.py" (Note s in the end). You should use:

```
from questions import Question
```

Make corrections on all import statements. I hope this helps.

Comment: it's just a typo sorry
but it has an error saying super() takes at least 1 argument

Comment: does it work after correction? what error message do you get?

Comment: traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Inheritance/venv/questiondemo1.py", line 43, in <module>
True
    first = AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Inheritance/venv/question.py", line 39, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: I tried to run your code and your code runs with 0 errors. Completely clueless,